# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection

Tags: python, openssl, pyodbc

when I try to connect to SQL Server, this error is thrown:
'08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)'.

> macOS Big Sur 11.6.1

Connection string;
import pyodbc

```
server = r"xxxERxxxSQLSERV"
db = "xxxDB"
user = "xxx"
password = "xxxx"
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server + ';DATABASE=' + db +';UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + password)
```

i update to openssl@1.1 but still can't connect to server.

> **$ openssl version** -> *OpenSSL 1.1.1m*

> **$ ls -l /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib** -> *lrwxr-xr-x  1 myusername  admin  28 Dec 22 22:13 /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -> ../Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m*

> **$ ls /usr/local/opt/** -> ca-certificates       libtool         mssql-tools     openssl         unixodbc
> gettext         m4          mssql-tools@17.8    openssl@1.0
> git         msodbcsql17     openjdk         openssl@1.1
> java            msodbcsql17@17.8    openjdk@17      pcre2